# AWS Step Functions - is there such a solution for Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, google-cloud-platform, serverless, aws-step-functions

At the moment I am investigating the possibility and the proper way of migrating complex web applications from AWS to GCP. There is actually no issues with [mapping](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/#service_comparisons) general compute and networking services from one provider to another, but I wonder if GCP has a service similar to [AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html)? I've already taken a look at Google [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) and Google [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/). The second one seems to be something like that, but I am not sure if it's the optimal solution.

So the question is what service from google provides same functionality as AWS Step Functions? And if there is no such - then combination of which services would you recommend to achieve effective orchestration of distributed tasks (primarily cloud functions). 
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**2021 Update**

As Brian de Alwis noted below, since this answer was written [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) is now generally available and is functionally similar to Step Functions.

---

**2019 Answer**

As far as I'm aware there's nothing specifically like Step Functions, but I have two strategies for creating these types of micro-service systems on Google Cloud.

**Strategy 1: Cloud Run/Cloud Functions with Pub/Sub**

Here I'd create microservices using Cloud Run or Cloud Functions and subscribe these functions to Pub/Sub topics.  That means that when Function A executes and completes it's work, it publishes a message to a specific topic with a data packet that any function subscribed to it will receive and execute.

For example you could create two topics named *FunctionASuccess* and *FunctionAError* and create two separate functions that subscribe to one or the other and handle the success and error use cases.

**Strategy 2: Firebase Functions with Firestore/Realtime Database**

Similarly to above I create Firebase Functions that watch for changes in Firestore or in the RTDB.

So *Function A* executes and completes its task, it saves a document to the FunctionAResults collection in Firestore or RTDB.  Functions that are subscribed to changes in the FunctionAResults collection are then executed and take it to the next step.

---

They both work reliably so I have no preference, but I typically go with the 2nd strategy if I'm utilizing other Firebase services.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, strategy #2 seems to be easier to control as I am able not only trigger tasks via firebase, but also store the state of each particular workflow execution.

Comment: I will accept this answer as the most suitable for today. Thanks.

Comment: While functionally both of the strategies would work - what about the visualization part - where you could design the flow visually?

Comment: Workflow seems to have some limitations. For example, if task3 depends on task1 and task2, how to handle this many to one dependence relationship?

Comment: @JerryAn Could be, I don't use it.  "Strategy 1" above is my recommended solution for limitless asynchronous microservice orchestration.

Answer (score 7):

[Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) was announced at Cloud Next On Air 2020.

Comment: Cloud workflows is definitely the closed thing to step functions that exists today

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [**Cloud Composer**](https://cloud.google.com/composer/). It's based on the open-source library [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) which allows you to define and orchestrate workflows in a similar way to step functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But If I understand this approach correctly - I will lose benefits of serverless, because seems I need to run composer environment on some dedicated machine. Am I right?

Comment: Things in the pipe. Stay tuned!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere soo how are the things in the pipe coming along? ^^

Comment: I can't share. Only Google PMs (Product managers) have this capability because I'm under NDA. However, Cloud Next on Air is coming this summer. You can expect new product launch in Beta.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm looking forward to it.